# can I return answer to else / if statements without assigning a variable?

Tags: javascript, object

I created an array with movie objects that iterate and print out results based on watched or not seen (if/else).

```
movies.forEach(function(arr){

    let answer = "you have "; <-- (omit this variable)
    if (arr.hasWatched) {
        answer += "watched ";  <-- (instead type: "you have watched ";)
    }
    else {
        answer += "not seen ";
    }
    answer += "\"" + arr.title + "\" - " + arr.rating + " stars";

    console.log (answer);
});
```

my question is: can i get answer to the if statement without creating the variable: answer? if so, how will i print out the statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the object and take a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for the wanted text.

For getting an alternative, you could utilize a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
movies.forEach(({ hasWatched, title, rating }) => {
    console.log(`you have ${hasWatched ? "watched" : "not seen"} "${title}" ${rating} stars`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator like this:

```
let answer = "you have " + (arr.hasWatched ? "watched " : "not seen ");
```

Theoretically, you could do a quite lengthy `console.log` to avoid the variable completely:

```
console.log("you have " + (arr.hasWatched ? "watched " : "not seen ") + "\"" + arr.title + "\" - " + arr.rating + " stars")
```

However, this is not very readable.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to do something conditionally, one is the `if` *statement* and one is the *ternary expression*. With the later, you don't need a variable at all:

```
 console.log( 
    "you have " +
   (arr.hasWatched ? "watched " : "not seen ") + // << ternary
   "\"" + arr.title + "\" - " + arr.rating + " stars"
 );
```

But I don't see any problem with that variable, readability is clearly better.